# C++ start new process and terminate the current one under linux

Tags: c++, linux, exec

This question has been asked several times here, but I can't find answer for the following situation:

My program uses statically linked libraries, which open file handles, so, I'm unable to set FD_CLOEXEC on those file handles

simply calling exec causes alot of errors in new process, because of unavailable file handles

Basically I need:
1. spawn new process without blocking current one
2. terminate current process (close all handles)

Can I do it on linux?

Comment: Why are you unable to set that on those handles? When you are about to exec, why don't you set it for every filehandle possible? Or close every filehandle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closing all filedescriptors should be as simple as

```
#include <unistd.h>

for (i=getdtablesize();i>=0;--i) 
     close(i); /* close all descriptors */
```

This is also a standard step during daemonizing, see e.g. http://www.enderunix.org/docs/eng/daemon.php